# Does the compiler eliminate unnecessary `dynamic_cast`s?

Tags: c++

I am writing a heavy-templatized application. Somewhere inside it, there is some code like that:

```
class TA {  };

class TX {

public:

    template <typename T>
    T &Foo(int a) {
        TA *pta;
        // here somehow initialize pta
        return *(dynamic_cast<T*>(pta));
    }

};
```

If I call `Foo` template member function with `T = TA`, will the dynamic cast `dynamic_cast<TA*>(pta)` [where `pta` is of type `TA*`] eliminated or optimized by the compiler? Or should I make some `type_traits` magic to eliminate it manually?

Comment: no. Using dynamic_cast you are forcing compiler to ignore the type cast, and have run-time take over the check.

Comment: Or you can make a template specialization which has a function to return your `pta` which will probably `inline` for the specialized version.

Comment: Optimizations are in principle optional, a compiler is never required to optimize (but most users expect it to optimize a bit). Look into the assembler code of your particular compiler (& compiler flags). E.g `g++ -O -Wall -fverbose-asm -S foo.cc` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), then look inside the generated `foo.s` assembler code

Comment: Although I've answered your question, now I'm questioning if your need that cast in the first place.

Comment: @rodrigo Yes, I need that cast. I have got a container of `shared_ptr`s of `TA` and I need to convert them to pointer to derived type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if the compiler can determine that the cast will always succeed, then it will omit the runtime check. And in your case, since the cast is trivial it cannot fail.

If the types are the same no conversion is done at all. In C++ standard, 5.2.7:

> `dynamic_cast<T>(v)`
>
> If the type of v is the same as T, or it is the same as T except that the class object type in T is more  cv-qualified than the class object type in v, the result is v (converted if necessary)

And if the type to be convertred to is a pointer or reference to a subclass, no runtime check either:

> If T is “pointer to cv1 B” and v has type “pointer to cv2 D” such that B is a base class of D, the result is a pointer to the unique B subobject of the D object pointed to by v.

That you have written a template and not simple code does not change the optimization decisions. Your code is equivalent to this one:

```
struct S {};
S *foo(S *a)
{
    return dynamic_cast<S*>(a);
}
```

That with basic optimizations (`g++ -O1`) will compile identically to:

```
S *foo2(S *a)
{
    return a;
}
```

Comment: The compiler *could* eliminate the `dynamic_cast` but does not have to. Not all compilers optimize equivalently.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Sure the compiler is not required to do any kind of optimization, but that is a low hanging fruit that any compiler I know of will do. Moreover, the OP code uses non-virtual types, so the runtime check is impossible anyway.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Actually the compiler is required to do runtime-checks only when `dynamic_cast` does a downcast. A upcast or a _selfcast_ shall not be checked. I've added a couple of quotes of the standard.